# Bootbox position top when dialog larger than screen

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal, bootbox

Im using http://bootboxjs.com/ and i have a form in one of these dialog boxes.
The form is larger than the screen and when bootbox has a dialog larger than the screen it vertically positions the dialog to the center of the screen. Forcing my users to scroll up.

[image]

Going to the website and resizing your browser to be smaller than any dialog box recreates this positioning. Is there a way to fix this behavior? I have been trying to fix this for sometime with no workaround yet.